# Add return false to parent link only with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list inside a toggled div...

```
<li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <ul stlye="display:none;">
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Child Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Ive written a piece of jQuery to toggle the display of the child UL only when a child link is clicked it no longer works (It doesnt go through to google), can anybody see where im going wrong?

```
//  Dropdown
$('.archives ul li a').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('ul').slideToggle();  
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Seem to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JRXxF/. What version of jQuery are you using and did something change in your code?

Comment: Sorry @j08691, the problem is if the child link is pointeing to a url, it no longer clicks through

Comment: It no longer works after the toggle or both before and after the toggle?

Comment: @Liam: It's very unclear A) What you **want** to have happen, and B) What's happening instead. Can you please state *clearly* what each of those things is?

Comment: Can you show us the html markup including `.archives`? Also, you seem to want using `.next("ul")` or `.siblings("ul")`, instead of `find()`ing all lists (on all levels)

Answer (score 1):

STYLE is spelled wrong.

```
stlye=
```

From your post's title it appears you want something like this...

```
$('.archives ul li a').click(function(){
    var $children = $(this).parent().find('ul');
    $children.slideToggle();
    return $children.length > 0 ? false : true;
});
```

Return will be false only when child ULs are found.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you've shown is inside a `ul` which is in turn inside an element with class `archives`, then the selector `.archives ul li a` matches **both** the parent and child anchors, because you've used a descendant selector, and so your handler gets called for the child, and the `return false;` prevents it from doing its default action (following the link).

If your goal is to have the handler triggered only for the earlier link and not for the child link, then you may need to be more specific. You haven't shown enough of your markup for us to help you *be* more specific, though. If I assume your markup looks something like this:

```
<div class="archives">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <ul style="display:none;">
          <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Child Link</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

...then the selector to match only the "Link" anchor and not the "Child Link" anchor would be `.archives > ul > li > a` (e.g., using *direct child* selectors).

Also note that you had `stlye` rather than `style`, but I assume that's just a typo in the question. *(Why don't people use copy and paste?! ;-) )*

Answer (score 0):

The ChildLink is also matched by your selector, and in the click handler you're preventing the default action (which would be "navigate to Google").

So you should adapt your selector to only get the toggle Link, or you use this:

```
$('.archives ul li a').click(function(e){
    if ($(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle().length) // if we found a list to toggle
        e.preventDefault(); // or return false
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Since your `return false` statement is cancelling the default link action, you need to be more specific so that you don't target the links that want to allow to continue to function.

Try this:

```
$('.archives > li > a').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('ul').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JRXxF/5/)**

By using the `>` child selector and changing the target to only the immediate child links of the outermost list, the sublinks won't be selected and will continue to work. In your code your `$('.archives ul li a')` will apply to any child links, not just the top level.

Comment: What's the downvote for? C'mon, whose the boneheaded coward that thinks that this is wrong?